# How can I remove and repair raised objects in a textured wall?

Tags: walls, painting, repainting, paint-removal

My buddies and I are planning to repaint a wall at our local community center, however we're new to the wall-painting process.

The wall is in the interior of the building.

The white wall has blue and orange hand-prints (by design), so there is paint "jutting" out with "peaks" up to 2-3 millimeters.

We intend to repaint the wall, however we first need to remove the "peaks".

I did some research on the different methods, but I don't know what is recommended for our situation:

- scraping the peaks off with scraper and then patching it with mud; or,
- sanding the peaks off and then patching it with orange peel; or,
- something else?

**How can we remove the "peaks" off of the hand-prints?**

---

**Update:** Removed question regarding how to cover orange paint, to focus the post on the "peaks".

Comment: I would sand then re texture so there won't be shadows of the hand prints in the new paint.

Comment: @EdBeal -- Would orange peel serve as the retexture?

Comment: Orange peal is a good way to re texture as long as it matches the original, adjusting the spatter for the same size and fade in the sanded areas will help to hide the repair. Don't mask the area when re texture or there will be lines,